# How to include the tab title when using set in slot to add panels

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I want to add panels to a tab panel. I do not know the names or number of  tab panels beforehand.

I have a slot that represents the tab panel.. TAB_PANEL_SLOT.

If I didn't have the requirement for a title on each tab panel I'd just do:

in Presenter:

```
addToSlot(TAB_PANEL_SLOT, presenter);
```

Which would then in turn call my view where I have:

```
@Override
public void addToSlot(Object slot, IsWidget content) {
    if (slot == TAB_PANEL_SLOT) {
       tabPanel.add(content); // ****
    } else {
       super.addToSlot(slot, content);
    }
}
```

Were it not for the requirement to include the tab's title when adding it to the tabPanel this would work great...

Is there a cunning way I can send through the tab's title?

Maybe I could override the getWidget call from my presenter and return something that embeds the title?

Comment: You can also ask GWT questions from GWT developers here: https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt